# Fetch JavaScript: Como puedo saber si una consulta se hizo correctamente

Tags: javascript

Ejecuto una función con un boton, esta función lo que hace es ejecutar fetch.
Actualmente el codigo de la funcion que se ejecuta es este:

```
fetch(url)
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                console.log('LA CONEXION FUE EXITOSA!!!-----');
                logSubida();
            }
            logSubida();
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(function(myJson) {
            document.getElementById('peli720').innerHTML += myJson + "</br>"
            console.log(myJson);
        });
```

La cosa es que cuando la conexión sea exitosa se ejecute la función **logSubida();** pero no he tenido suerte.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN #1**
el código funciona pero la función **logSubida()** se ejecuta después que el script termina de ejecutarse completamente.

Hay alguna manera de poder ejecutar dicha función cuando se haga la petición al servidor correctamente?

Comment: Que te devuelve el response?

Comment: Al hacer console.log(response); no me devuelve nada, pero la conexión se establece porque logro ver de manera independiente el log ejecutando la funcion logSubida(); por aparte

Comment: Deberías tener después del `.then` un `.catch` que es la parte de la promesa que se ejecutará si esta queda en estado de `rejected`

Comment: Entiendo, podrías darme un ejemplo por favor. Perdón por mi impertinencia pero apenas estoy aprendiendo javascript

Comment: Prueba a usar response.status para verificar si el servidor te devuelve una respuesta exitosa

Comment: Igual, no muestra nada. Es como si no se ejecutara fetch. Noce si yo lo estoy haciendo mal, me podrían dar un ejemplo por favor.

Comment: Deberías mostrar en la pregunta, toda la parte de tu código en donde ejecutas fetch() en ese caso.

Comment: Listo. agregue la manera en que se ejecuta la función, la verdad es algo básico la manera de ejecución, solo es con un botón el cual llama a la función que solo tiene el código que espesifique.

Answer (score 1):

La llamada e `fetch` es asíncrona, por lo tanto, tienes que crear un código en el cual pases los datos a `logSubida` una vez `fetch` haya finalizado.

La forma de hacerlo, en base a la sintaxis de tu código sería:

```js
var btnGo = document.getElementById('btnGo');
var divPeli = document.getElementById('peli720');

btnGo.addEventListener("click", logFetch, false);

function logFetch() {
  var url = this.value;
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      /* 
        Puedes también hacer uso de json aquí
        con toda seguridad.
        Para prueba, pondremos el id aquí
      */
      divPeli.innerHTML += json.id + "<br />";
      logSubida(json);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error('fetch failed', err.message);
    });
}

function logSubida(json) {
  console.log(json);
  divPeli.innerHTML += json.title;
}
```

```html
<button id="btnGo" value="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1">Launch Fetch</button>
<div id="peli720">
  <hr />
</div>
```

También podrías usar las funciones asíncronas (`async`), que hacen el código un poco más legible, ya que desaparecen todos los callback.

Este código es similar al anterior.

```js
var btnGo = document.getElementById('btnGo');
var divPeli = document.getElementById('peli720');

btnGo.addEventListener("click", logFetch, false);

async function logFetch() {
  try {
    var url = this.value;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const json = await response.json();
    /* 
      Puedes también hacer uso de json aquí
      con toda seguridad
      Para prueba asignaremos un dato del json
    */
    divPeli.innerHTML += json.id + "<br />";
    logSubida(json);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('fetch failed', err.message);
  }
}

function logSubida(json) {
  divPeli.innerHTML += json.title + "<br />";
  console.log(json);
}
```

```html
<button id="btnGo" value="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1">Launch Fetch</button>
<div id="peli720">
  <hr />
</div>
```

Cabe decir que por cualquiera de los dos que optes, debes saber que desde dentro del bloque de `fetch` puedes usar los datos y modificar cualquier elemento del DOM, como de hecho ocurre en el ejemplo al setear el `id`.

Para más detalles sobre las funciones asíncronas puedes ver [*Funciones asincrónicas - hacen promesas amigablemente*](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions?hl=es) de Jake Archibald.